# Enthought Canopy lapacke

Tags: cython, enthought, lapack, canopy, lapacke

It seems that the simplest way of calling lapack functions from cython is to use lapacke.

I would like to use the lapack functions that come with Enthought Canopy in the libmkl_* dynamic libraries.

However, I cannot find lapacke.h anywhere in Canopy. Is there any way I can use lapacke without making a separate installation of lapack?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114100/calling-dot-products-and-linear-algebra-operations-in-cython/16153914#16153914 The answer there is very good.

Comment: Another answer is also helpful. See [stackoverflow.com/questions/14864895/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864895/distributing-cython-based-extensions-using-lapack)

Comment: To help with linking to the mkl .so (or .dylib) files, use the [mkl link line advisor](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor). I will try to put together a working answer and post it soon.

Comment: By the way, if you are looking at using your own installation of BLAS and LAPACK, I would recommend looking at https://github.com/tokyo/tokyo I haven't used it myself, but it looks promising.